# Logback doesn't change log level in runtime

Tags: logback, log-level

I am using your com.github.tony19:logback-android:1.1.1-12 library.

After I change my Log Level in Property file, I expect that the Log Level is changed in runtime. But ist doesn't work.

Do you know what could be a Problem?

I have set scan=true and scanPeriod=2 seconds. I have every time after I set the change in properties file to restart the Android App. Because only in this way works.

```
logback.properties: 

root.loglevel=OFF

logback.xml

<include file="${EXT_DIR}/Download/de.hermes.alpha/assets/logbackincludedfile.xml"
    optional="true" />
<root level="${root.loglevel:-DEBUG}">
    <appender-ref ref="logcat" />
    <appender-ref ref="logstash" />
    <appender-ref ref="rollingLogFile" />
</root>
```

Regards, Neda

Answer (score 1):

### `scan` feature broken in `1.1.1-12`

There's currently a bug in `1.1.1-12` that prevents the file-change detection from occurring, which blocks the `scan` feature you're seeking. If you enable `<configuration debug="true">`, you should see this error message in LogCat:

```
Due to missing top level configuration file, automatic reconfiguration is impossible.
```

This will be fixed in the next release. (*Tracked in `logback-android` Issue [#182](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues/182)*)

#### Only `included` files are scanned

Your comment below makes an incorrect assumption that files specified in `<property>` are scanned:

> After I change my Log Level in Property file, I expect that the Log Level is changed in runtime.

The `.properties` file (included via `<property file="...">`) does not get scanned. In this case, only files from `<include file="...">` are scanned periodically when `<configuration scan="true">`.